# What Audio Format Is This?

Tags: audio, file-format

I'm having trouble finding something to play this audio file, can anybody help? All I know is its file extension and it plays via Androids MediaPlayer. MediaInfo and GSpot doesn't give me anything.

http://c968439.r39.cf3.rackcdn.com/USQX91201249.aud

**EDIT**: I realized it was missing some extra "header" information. The final result is: http://wikisend.com/download/941432/GBARL1201392.mp4. I now know this file is an MP4-2 audio file yet I still can't play it in any player.

Comment: *> AUD is a file extension for an audio file using AUD compression. AUD compression was created by Westwood Studios and is used in several computer games, including Command and Conquer and Red Alert. AUD files can be opened by the NICE Media Player.*

Comment: Ahh, interestingly TRID and the file command on linux don't know what it is either.

Comment: You might tell us what OS you would like to play this in?

Comment: Windows. I'm thinking its some proprietary format, although it does play fine via Androids [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [someone cracked the compression](http://dune2k.com/Duniverse/Games/Dune2000/Downloads/Audio),  a command line program Aud2Wav (win32bit only), on that same page is an old plugin for [older versions of Winamp player](http://www.oldversion.com/Winamp.html).

[Looks like Nice Media Player](http://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=Nice+Media+Player&oq=Nice+Media+Player&gs_l=hp.12..0l2j0i30j0i10i30.1266.4413.0.7675.17.17.0.0.0.0.73.1086.17.17.0.les%3Beqn%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D1%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue..0.0...1c.1.3rTPMXnmsY0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=8235ac65df7283a3&bpcl=38093640&biw=1310&bih=727) is the only recent player option I can find as mentioned by others, but cannot find a download source that does not give me the willies.

Edit: tried to convert your sample .aud file but it failed saying "error opening the file", more than likely the compression has changed over the years, AUD2WAV was coded in 1998.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Plugins/foo-aud.shtml) [old](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?s=&showtopic=5209&view=findpost&p=276662) foobar2000 plugin might also help (you can get older versions of foobar from [here](http://www.oldversion.com/Foobar2000.html)).

Comment: foobar2000 doesn't work.